# ACF drag and drop order change after passing few minutes

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

In my WordPress site, I want to make the ACF in the correct order. So I dragged and saved ACF. After saving and refreshing the page, the ACF fields are in the correct order position. But after passing a few minutes ACF order gets change. Any idea to fix this issue?

Note: ACF order number doesn't match with my requirement because the same ACF field is used in different pages.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: What order do you mean? The order in which ACF fields are shown below the post? The order of Repeater fields? The order of a Post Object fields with multiselect?

Comment: I mean the order of the Advanced Custom Fields when we add ACF to the page/post. -@Damocles